# Unable to run pip on venv (Group Policy error) - VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-venv, group-policy

I'm trying to run a small **Python script** using a **venv** on VS Code, the script uses two external packages listed in the requirements.txt file included on the scripts package.

When I try to run the script, I get the following error because one of the external packages is missing:

```
  File "C:\Users\somepath\scriptfolder\thescript.py", line 17, in <module>
    import aiofiles
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiofiles'
```

So I try to install the missing external package manually using the PIP command, but then I get the following error

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\somepath\scriptfolder> pip install aiofiles==22.1.0
Program 'pip.exe' failed to run: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administratorAt line:1 char:1
+ pip install aiofiles==22.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install aiofiles==22.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
 
(.venv) PS C:\Users\somepath\scriptfolder>
```

**Relevant notes:**

- Python interpreter works fine on both venv and local drive (e.g. run
  from cmd).
- PIP is installed correctly on Windows (runs fine when I
  run it from cmd)
- If I look in the scriptfolder\venv\Scripts folder I can see the following:

> ```
> activate.bat
> deactivate.bat
> python.exe
> pip.exe
> pip3.11.exe
> pythonw.exe
> ```

**I would really appreciate any feedback on this issue.**

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you using corporate laptop? If so, it is like your version of python.exe and pip.exe was blocked by group policy.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install aiofiles`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thanks for your reply. This command `python3 -m pip install aiofiles` ran fine in VSCode Terminal, but it installed the pip package into the main Python311\Lib\site-packages main folder. I temporarily fixed the problem by copying the entire folders for the missing packages from my `Python311\Lib\site-packages` to my venv `venv\Lib\site-packages\` directory.

Comment: activate your virtual env, then run the the command, it will be saved there

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using the following command (specify the python environment using the full python interpreter path)

```
path\to\scriptfolder\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install aiofiles==22.1.0
```